# Populate a GridView with data binding only once per execution

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, data-binding, uwp

I am currently making a UWP app with XAML and C#, but I hit a major issue. The home page contains 700+ items, all stored in a SQLite database and populated at runtime. Each time I navigate out and return to the page, the app freezes for a while and then displays the home page... How can I populate it only once, even if it is taking all my startup time?

My code to populate looks like that (in *.xaml.cs):

```
public sealed partial class MainView : Page
{
    // Creates the Collection
    public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<sqlitetable> chooseaname = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<sqlitetable>();

    public MainView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        // Populates the Collection
        using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), System.IO.Path.Combine(Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "Assets", "database.db")))
        {
            foreach (var entry in db.Table<sqlitetable>())
            {
                chooseaname.Add(new sqlitetable { Image = "/Assets/pics/" + entry.ID + ".png", Name = entry.Name, Type1 = "/Assets/Types/" + entry.Type1 + ".png", Type2 = "/Assets/Types/" + entry.Type2 + ".png", dummyID = "# " + entry.ID.ToString("000") });
            }
        }

        // Sets the binding
        mainView.ItemsSource = chooseaname;
    }
```

Comment: What does your code look like? In simplified form?

Comment: What are you "populating"? If the items are going directly to the page, you'll almost *have* to populate it every time. If they're going to a collection somewhere else, that's easy enough.

Comment: @PetterHesselberg Done, but I don't think that the way I am making it will make it through the changes for populating only once.

Comment: @RareNCool A GridView in the page.

Comment: Then you'll either have to populate it every time or else store the items in a singleton class or something similar.

Comment: Where did pokedex come from?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick-and-dirty approach to loading your data only once:

```
public sealed partial class MainView : Page
{
    private static IList<sqlitetable> data = null;

    public IList<sqlitetable> Data
    {
        get
        {
            if (data == null)
            {
                data = new List<sqlitetable>();

                // Populates the Collection
                using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), Path.Combine(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "Assets", "database.db")))
                {
                    foreach (var entry in db.Table<sqlitetable>())
                    {
                        data.Add(new sqlitetable { Image = "/Assets/pics/" + entry.ID + ".png", Name = entry.Name, Type1 = "/Assets/Types/" + entry.Type1 + ".png", Type2 = "/Assets/Types/" + entry.Type2 + ".png", dummyID = "# " + entry.ID.ToString("000") });
                    }
                }
            }

            return data;
        }
    }

    public MainView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        gridView.ItemsSource = Data;
    }
}
```

Consider storing the data in a separate view model class and instantiate it *once* using either the singleton pattern or a dependency injection framework. It won't work any better, but will improve maintainability by separating concerns.

Also consider binding to your data from XAML instead of setting the `ItemsSource` in code, e.g.:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Data, Mode=OneTime}" />
```

Comment: At `data.Add(...)`, I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: I found something else: `data` is `readonly`, so it can't be assigned in the `get` method. I'll edit your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't get this lag anymore, even if the initial loading is a bit long... ;P     Putting the data in a separated view model is not useful in my case, because the ObservableCollection is only used in this page and nowhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! That's what I get for editing code after it has left Visual Studio. :-)

Comment: You might want to look at your DB config, though -- indexes and such. Not my area, but I know the impact can be huge. Loading 700+ items from a DB is what a DB is supposedly good at, so perhaps there are gains to be had here as well.

Comment: A command line prompt can easily output those 700+ entries in a flash, but I haven't made a check for how time does it takes to populate the entries in the app. I think that the long startup time is more related to the fact it is an UWP that is debugging. Starting it without debugging takes 1 or 2 seconds, while when debugging, it takes up to 30 seconds.